# How can i get my java code to terminate after the user inputs the password wrong 3 times in Java

Tags: javascript, java

Code runs but my directions is for the program to terminate after the user inputs the password wrong 3 times.

[First image is the first half of the code and validating the password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih7ip.png)

[Next is the main method and how the user interacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIYL2.png)

Comment: You could put ```System.exit(0)``` instead of break

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

You can exit a prgramm with `System.exit(0)`

So you could change your code to this:

```
if (count ==2){
     System.exit(0);
   }
```